# Static friction components on a car while turning with both centripetal and tangential acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

When a car is taking a turn on a horizontal road with both centripetal and tangential acceleration, how do the components of the static friction $\mu N$ provide both the centripetal and tangential acceleration when the maximum centripetal acceleration itself is $\mu N$?

Answer (score 1):

**Centripetal acceleration**: Necessary acceleration for a body to be in circular motion.

**Tangential acceleration**: It is because of change in magnitude of velocity. It is not a necessary acceleration for circular motion.

While a car takes turn on horizontal road, it's motion now changed from translation to circular motion. We know that in circular motion velocity vector is given by tangent drawn to circle at that point. Let $V$ be the velocity of the car. $V_{x}$ be the horizontal component and $V_{y}$ be the vertical component **considering road as reference plane**.

Here the components of friction are $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$.

[image]

Forward velocity $V_{y}$ is due to driving force of the car by it's engine. As the car is in motion $f_{y}$ is **kinetic friction** pulling the car in backward direction but it is always less than the driving force.

Here you considered circular motion to be non uniform, so $V$ is not constant. Due to change in magnitude of $V$ there will be tangential acceleration on the car.

Where as the the horizontal component of friction $f_{x}$ is acting towards center, it is balanced by an outward centrifugal force $mv^2/r$ where r is the radius of the circular path. So $f_{x}$ is **static friction**. Here $f_{x}$ is providing centripetal acceleration.

As the car successfully taking a turn $$f_{x} \geqslant f_{L}$$

Here $f_{L}$ is limiting friction and is equal to $\mu_{s} N$ where $\mu_{s}$ is coefficient of static friction.

$\Rightarrow$  $mv^2/r \geqslant \mu_{s} N $

So, in this case **static friction only provides centripetal acceleration where as tangential acceleration caused due to change in magnitude of
Velocity of the car.**